# PHP list top 10 highest vaules in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to list the top highest 10 values in my MySQL table.

I've tried this:

```
              $SQL = ("SELECT * Rating FROM download_manager ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10;");
              $results = mysqli_query($SQL);
              var_dump($results);
```

However that returns a NULL, also I'd need it to echo back two rows and not the whole table...

DB Structure:  id | filename | downloads

I need to just echo back the top 10 highest downloads and the associated filename.

Update:

Rating is not the table, connection is done through a require connect. I've removed the () however still get a null.

Comment: what is with the ( ) in $SQL huh... go with `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM download_manager ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10";`  Ideally don't do select * though, choose your columns

Comment: is *Rating*  in the table or not ?

Comment: also where is your connection

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
$SQL = "SELECT Rating FROM download_manager ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10;";
              $results = mysqli_query($SQL);
              var_dump($results);
```